# Construct an O(n) average case algorithm to find closest m points from a list of n points

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, complexity-theory

We need to construct an algorithm, given a list of n points in the Cartesian plane, the closest m (m is not constant, and less than or equal to n) points to the origin. This algorithm needs to work in O(n) average time, which is what I've been struggling with.

My initial idea was to sort the list based on the distance of each point from the origin, and select the first $m$ points from the sorted list. However, all the sorting algorithms I know work in O(nlogn) average time. Is there another way to do this, using the properties of the cartesian plane?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Compute the distance to each point. Then use quick select to find the closest points.

Comment: we need to print m closest points, which is less than or equal to n. On average, quick select for m items would be O(n^2) time, no?

Comment: You can do it with a heap in O(n log m) time. The heap always contains the m closest points found so far.

Comment: On average, quick select is O(n). Worst case quick select is O(n^2). In that respect, quick select is similar to quick sort. Quick sort is O(nlogn) on average, and O(n^2) worst case.

Comment: quick select would return the kth smallest element. we need m of those, making the average time O(nm). Since m is \leq n, this would be O(n^2) time.

Comment: Quick select works by putting `m-1` smaller elements to the left of the mth smallest element, and the rest of the elements to the right. So when quick select is done, the first `m` elements in the array are the smallest `m` elements. They just aren't in any particular order. That's what allows it to be faster than sorting.

Comment: ah, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @Attila1177298 Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [QuickSelect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm to find the m-th closest point to the origin.  This will leave the list partitioned into the closest m points, followed by the farther points.